# Hungarian: Repeat Step X through Step Y

Tags: hungarian

I have an automated process that generates links to steps that are dynamically numbered.

In English we have some documents with XML (DITA) source such as:

`Repeat <xref> through <xref> for each nozzle.`

It goes through a transformation process and pulls in the word "Step", determines the appropriate number, and creates a link around the word and number.

`Repeat Step 1 through Step 4 for each nozzle.`

I had originally planned on customizing the process so that the word step came before or after the number, but I am now learning that some languages are much more complex. (Such as Hungarian.)

My original incorrect translation:

`Mindegyik fúvóka esetében ismételje meg az lépés 1–lépés 4t.`

In this instance a Hungarian user has asked for us to use:

`Mindegyik fúvóka esetében ismételje meg az 1-4. lépést`

This breaks my pattern. Is there a more generic way to use lépés (Step) without conjugation to follow the same pattern as it does in English?

The same question for singular:

Original EN:

`You can also create a stain program by selecting Select Program, then Edit, then proceeding with Step 4.`

My original incorrect translation:

`Festési programot úgy is létrehozhat, ha kiválasztja a Programválasztás, majd a
Szerkesztés gombot, majd a lépés 4 sel folytatja.`

Recommended translation:

`Festési programot úgy is létrehozhat, ha kiválasztja a Programválasztás, majd a Szerkesztés gombot, majd 4. Lépéssel folytatja.`

Is there a way to state the same sentence without conjugating the word "Step" (Lépéssel)?

Comment: Hello mkaatman and welcome to Linguistics.SE. Unfortunately, questions about translation are off topic unless they are about linguistic aspects of languages. Consider finding some Hungarian-speaking community; I'm not aware of one within the Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hey Bytebuster, I have the translations. I was actually looking for the linguistic rules surrounding my use case. Maybe I didn't state the questions clearly enough.

Comment: @mkaatman: Please feel free to edit your question at any time to make it more clear. I'm sure if you do it will remain open and ought to get some serious attempts at answering.

Comment: In fact this question seems to me the perfect kind of question for [the proposed new Stack Exchange site "Languages"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61823/languages/62237). Not all questions about languages are linguistics question. Please consider following the proposal. There are not "linguistic rules" they are Hungarian grammar rules.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can uses lépés individually, and it's recognizable, but it's not very natural Hungarian looking.